# Function Compare on Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with function Compare-Object from PowerShell. I have two `.csv` i need to compare and output difference and properties

```
My code and my file:

$old = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\New folder\old.csv" 
$new = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\New folder\new.csv" 
Compare-Object $old $new -Property 'First Name','Last Name' |  Export-Csv -Path $total -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

My first file to compare (old) old.csv (UTF8 Encoding)

```
First Name,Last Name
Luca,Frattinò
Franco,Avanè
```

My second file to compare (new) new.csv (UTF8 Encoding)

```
First Name,Last Name
Luca,Grattinò
Franco,Savanè
```

The result:

```
"First Name","Last Name","SideIndicator"
"Luca","Grattin�","=>"
"Franco","Savan�","=>"
"Luca","Frattin�","<="
"Franco","Avan","<="
```

If i try to not export to csv same result

@Ranadip Dutta: Already tried but no success

All works but if I have field with special character I have issue with output
on output directly to PowerShell or to export with Encoding Unicode I have strange character like `c�` how to format `Compare-Object` to use UTF8 or Unicode to resolve the `Compare-Object`.

Comment: You can change the default encoding and can try getting it. Here is the [LINK](https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/03/03/understanding-default-encoding-and-change-the-same-in-powershell/)

Comment: Can you include sample file (and remember to specify its encoding) so that anyone can reproduce your issue? Take a look at how to create [mcve].

Comment: It works for me with an accent.  You shouldn't have to use -encoding with import-csv if the file has an encoding signature.  But you definitely need -encoding with export-csv.

Comment: I have added more detail, aleady tried with default encoding

Comment: Please @reply people to notify them.  It all works ok for me in windows 10 powershell 5.1.  Do $old and $new look normal?  Do old.csv and new.csv look ok in notepad, and "save as" says the type is utf8?  The only problem I have is export-csv with no encoding.  Then it's ascii and the accents are turned into "?".  Even csv's with utf8 no bom's created in ps 6 work ok.